# Factorial program prints multiple numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial

I am learning Python, stuck in factorial program, I am getting multiple lines of output instead of single line output.

Program I wrote

```
num = int (input ("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1

if num == 0:
    print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")
elif num <0:
    print ("Error, negative number does not have factorial")
else:
     for i in range (2, num +1):
            factorial = factorial*i
            print ("the factorial is: ", factorial)
```

getting output as below.

```
Enter a number: 4
the factorial is:  2
the factorial is:  6
the factorial is:  24
```

I am looking for single line answer but getting multiple lines, I am unable to understand why.

Comment: The code produces multiple lines of output because it prints in a for-loop that repeats multiple times. Take the print out of the loop and it will print only once.

Comment: You're getting multiple outputs because you're calling `print` multiple times. Move the print statement outside (after) the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an explicit test for the input being equal to 0. The correct result can be obtained by carefully constructing the range.

Do not print the intermediate value(s) within the loop - just do it once after the loop terminates.

Using Python 3.8+ you could do it like this:

```
if (n := int(input('Input value for n: '))) < 0:
    print('Unable to calculate factorial of a negative number')
else:
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        f *= i
    print(f'{n}! = {f}')
```

If n < 2 (but not negative) the loop will not be entered and so the value of 1 initially assigned to *f* will be the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Because your output has multiple answer. İnstead of range use while.

```
num = int (input ("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1
i=1
if num == 0:
    print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")
elif num <0:
    print ("Error, negative number does not have factorial")
else:
     while i<=num:
       factorial = factorial*i
       i=i+1
     print ("the factorial is: ", factorial)
```

Or,

```
num = int (input ("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1

if num == 0:
    print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")
elif num <0:
    print ("Error, negative number does not have factorial")
else:
     for i in range (2, num +1):
            factorial = factorial*i
     print ("the factorial is: ", factorial)
```

There is easiest way:

```
import math
num = int (input ("Enter a number: "))
if num == 0:
    print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")
elif num <0:
    print ("Error, negative number does not have factorial")
else:
     factorial=math.factorial(num)
     print ("the factorial is: ", factorial)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int (input ("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1
if num == 0:
    print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")
elif num <0:
    print ("Error, negative number does not have factorial")
else:
    for i in range (2, num +1):
        factorial = factorial*i
print ("the factorial is: ", factorial)
```

Answer (score -2):

`print ("the factorial is: ", factorial)`
currently, your print statement is under the scope of for loop that's why after each iteration print statement is also evaluated. so to avoid this simply move the print statement from the scope of for loop

```
num = int (input ("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1

if num == 0:
    print ("The factorial of 0 is 1")
elif num <0:
    print ("Error, negative number does not have factorial")
else:
     for i in range (2, num +1):
            factorial = factorial*i
print ("the factorial is: ", factorial)
```

Comment: Consider what happens with this code when the input is a negative integer. Hint: *print()* will be invoked twice